# Spark's cartesian function produces undesirable result

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cartesian

I encounter an undesirable result with Spark's cartesian function. It is not reproducible with small dataset; it only persists with large dataset.

For example:

**Small dataset**

```
a = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = sc.parallelize([(100, 150), (200, 250), (300, 350), (400, 450), (500, 550)])
c = a.cartesian(b)
print c.collect()
print c.count()
```

> print c.collect()
>
> > [(1, (100, 150)), (1, (200, 250)), (2, (100, 150)), (2, (200, 250)), (1, (300, 350)), (1, (400, 450)), (2, (300, 350)), (2, (400, 450)), (1, (500, 550)), (2, (500, 550)), (3, (100, 150)), (3, (200, 250)), (4, (100, 150)), (4, (200, 250)), (5, (100, 150)), (5, (200, 250)), (3, (300, 350)), (3, (400, 450)), (4, (300, 350)), (4, (400, 450)), (3, (500, 550)), (4, (500, 550)), (5, (300, 350)), (5, (400, 450)), (5, (500, 550))]
>
> print c.count()
>
> > 25

Since "a" has 5 elements and "b" has 5 elements, the cartesian product of the two is 25 elements. However, with large dataset, the cartesian has a size smaller than what is expected.

**Large dataset**

```
x = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print x.collect()
"""
y is a RDD in the same format as b.
y.count() == 19475211
""" 
print y.take(5)

z = x.cartesian(y)
print z.take(5)
print z.count()
```

> print x.collect()
>
> > [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
>
> print y.take(5)
>
> > [(5120, 2560), (5120, 3840), (5120, 520), (5120, 3500), (5120, 2060)]
>
> print z.take(5)
>
> > [(1, (5120, 2560)), (1, (5120, 3840)), (1, (5120, 520)), (5120, (3500, 1)), (5120, (2060, 1))]
>
> print z.count()
>
> > 7451200

If you noticed with the large dataset, when you take the cartesian of x and y, the 4th element of z is (5120, (3500, 1)) instead of (1, (5120, 3500)). The 5th element of z is (5120, (2060, 1)) instead of (1, (5120, 2060)).

Also, the size of z is 7451200 instead of 19475211 * 5 = 97376055.

What causes this problem to occur? And what is the solution to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Every tuple pair in y is unique, meaning there will not be the same tuple pair repeated.

Comment: As far as I can tell `count` is not reproducibly with current version and the issue (ordering) is an expected behavior. Spark doesn't provide any guarantees about the order of values in case like this.

Comment: Could you provide more details (Spark version, Python version, mode)?

Comment: However, you can sort the `RDD`

Comment: sorting the RDD did not resolve the issue either

Comment: spark version 1.5.2, python version 2.7.10

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not figured out why this is happening, I did resolve the issue. I first broadcast the list of x and then perform a flat map operation on y. The result z is what I expected the result to be.

```
x = sc.broadcast([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
z = y.flatMap(lambda (y_1, y_2): [(x_elt, (y_1, y_2)) for x_elt in x.value])
```